# SQL Query with Foreign Key (missing data, return default value)

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have a table called

```
"machine" (columns: machine_id(pk),year, site, color)
```

and a table called

```
"machine_description" (columns: machine_id(fk), language, description)
```

I would like to create a sql query where I can type in the preferred language and it returns all machines with the appropriate description in the preferred language. (I have made it)

```
SELECT *
FROM machine 
LEFT JOIN machine_description ON machine.machine_id = machine_description.machine_id 
WHERE machine_description.description = "german";
```

My problem, however, is that with some machines the description is not available in the desired language. In this case, the description should be returned in english by default instead of the desired language.
How can I solve this problem?
See Image

Thank you very much for your answer.
PS. I am quite new in this field...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jL1BE.png)

Comment: On a side note: Please use single quotes for string literals (`'german'`), because double quotes are for names in SQL. Mixing the two can lead to problems.

Answer (score 0):

As of MySQL 8 you can use window functions for the ranking (select both German and English first, then rank the former higher than the latter, and keep the better ranked rows):

```
select *
from
(
  select
    m.*,
    md.*,
    row_number() over (partition by m.machine_id order by language desc) as rn
  from machine m
  join machine_description md on md.machine_id = m. machine_id
                              and md.language in ('german', 'english')
) both
where rn = 1;
```

Make this a left outer join, if you want to allow for the case that neither the desired language nor English is available and you want to show the machine still.

But you can probably also use a subquery in the select clause:

```
select m.*
  (
    select md.description
    from machine_description md
    where md.machine_id = m. machine_id
    and md.language in ('german', 'english')
    order by md.language desc -- German before English
    limit 1
  ) as descr
from machine m;
```

I am sorting by language descending so as to get German before English. For a more general solution sort with `CASE WHEN`:

```
order by case when md.language = 'english' then 1 else 0 end
```

or just

```
order by (md.language = 'english')
```

because true is 1 and false is 0 in MySQL.